# What to look for in a touchscreen for RPi?

Tags: touchscreen

I would like to build a project on RPi with touchscreen, and wonder what to look for beyond the official (rather expensive) ones.

How can I tell whether a screen will work or not?  What kind of connections should it use?  Is there anything to beware of?

Can I use the screen from an old tablet if I take it apart?

Comment: Welcome -- but shopping recommendations are explicitly [off-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  If you want to change the question to what features/characteristics to look for in a touchscreen for the Pi, that kind of question is okay (but asking which one to buy or where to buy it is not).

Comment: @goldilocks thank you. I edited question. Is it OK?

Comment: How about this?  Note that  there are a lot of touchscreens that are sold "for Raspberry Pi" that are not the official ones; if you find one specific that you want to use and want to know if it will work and what issues there might be with it, that is an okay question too.  WRT using the screen from an old tablet: No, it is not feasible.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is that the seller makes references to device tree overlays. This guarantees that the driver is maintained by Linux/Raspbian and will always be updated and working, whether the manufacturer goes bankrupt or not.

This is infinitely better than random images with random included drivers. Those are of no use if you are **already** using a configured Raspbian or Arch Linux ARM system.

Comment: Good advice - to late for me. I shot a cheap one on amazon and now it's lying around because the only image reported to work with this isn't up to date and I didn't find the time to check if I can live with it or getting it to work at all

Comment: What is *device tree overlay*? Ok.. here.. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md